# Encoding - Convert US-ASCII to UTF-8?

Tags: java

My default Charset on my Linux machine is US-ASCII. If I upload a File with umlauts, i have a problem with the encoding.

In the example i create a File with the name standü.png. 
If I do

```
new String(f.getName().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()),"UTF-8");
```

my outcome is stand?.png. But I want standü.png (with umlauts)

```
//Default Charset is US-ASCII
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());

    String s = "standü.png";

    File f = new File(s);

    String newstr = new String(f.getName().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()),"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(newstr);
```

My Output is:

```
US-ASCII
stand?.png
```

Comment: If you say your default charset is ASCII, don't you need something in place of "Charset.defaultCharset()".

Comment: Why do anything at all? `f.getName()` is already returning a string (with umlauts). The only thing your weird code is doing, is mangling it up. Stop that. --- What are you even *trying* to do here? What perceived problem are you *actually* trying to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in America, near San Francisco, on a Mac, running garden variety Java 8. When I run your code, as is, I get the umlaut:

```
UTF-8
standü.png
```

I kinda figured I'd get this, because I know from past experience that my default Charset is some kind of unicode that will preserve foreign characters.  Why is your default Charset ASCII?  That seems to be your problem.

As I said in my comment, I think you can change "Charset.defaultCharset()" to "Charset.forName("UTF-8") to fix your problem.  I can't be sure, but if I set it to "Charset.forName("ASCII"), then I get the output you do.  So it seems this should fix things for you.

So just change:

```
String newstr = new String(f.getName().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()),"UTF-8");
```

to:

```
String newstr = new String(f.getName().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
```

Also, won't this give you your umlaut:

```
String newstr = f.getName();
System.out.println(newstr);
```

as everything stays unicode all the way along, if I understand correctly. The problem comes in when you have to convert the name to a byte stream.  If you don't have to do that, you'll be fine.  If you do, then use UTF-8 explicitly instead of the default charset and I think you'll be good too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create on the file system a file having a name containing non-ASCII characters, you don't actually need any conversion.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new File("ü").createNewFile();
  }
}
```

This will actually create a file named "ü" on my filesystem. Note that I'm on Linux and that the file names are actually a sequence of bytes (in this case, it would be 0xC3 0xBC). The OS doesn't interpret the filename as a string. Programs like `ls` will, however. What they're going to use to interpret the sequence depends on the locale.

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ls 
ü
$ LC_ALL=C ls 
''$'\303\274'
```

Be also careful about how you determine encoding correctness. When you output something on the console, there's also an encoding there and if it's not set properly you might come to the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

You need to start the JVM with an appropriate system property `file.encoding` and set it to the encoding of the filenames in the file system. Since the filenames on UNIX-like operating systems are typically byte strings instead of character strings, you will have to try which one is correct: `UTF-8` (probably) or `ISO-8859-1` (less likely). One of these should work.

The name of the property is not listed in [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--) but when you list the properties, you will easily its current value.

The property probably needs to be set very early, ideally via the `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` command line option.

Comment: I think this is a good solution too.  With my solution, he should be able to fix his problems in code.  With yours, he could set it once and forget it, and not have to worry about anything in his code.  Seems strange that the default is ASCII.

Comment: `file.encoding` controls the encoding used to read/write the *content* of the file. It has no impact on how the file *name* is handled.